# C++ Builder how to clear keys pressed during MessageBox

Tags: c++, messagebox, builder

I use Embarcaderro C++ Builder XE7 on my Windows 7.

I have a few hotkeys in my forms defined like this:

```
void __fastcall Twindow::FormKeyUp(TObject *Sender, WORD &Key, TShiftState Shift)
{
    switch(Key)
    {
        case vkEscape:
            Close();
            break;
        //and other cases for different keys
    }
}
```

At some point my form creates message box with question. And it works perfectly fine, but the problem starts when somebody decides to use keyboard to answer message box. If I hit ESC to close this message box, that escape button message surely closes box but it is also sent to the form and the form responds in a way defined above (it closes).

I think I may have to somehow clear pending messages before they are sent and answered... How do I do this?

My message box code looks like this:

```
if(Application->MessageBoxW(L"Do you want to procees?", L"Box?", MB_OKCANCEL) == ID_OK)
{
    //proceed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the right code:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::FormKeyUp(TObject *Sender, WORD &Key, TShiftState Shift)
{
    switch(Key)
    {
        case VK_ESCAPE:
            if(!CloseForm)
                Close();
            break;
        // And other cases for different keys
    }
}

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    CloseForm = Application->MessageBoxA("Save the file?", "Save As", 1) != IDOK;
}

void __fastcall TForm1::FormKeyPress(TObject *Sender, char &Key)
{
    CloseForm = false;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).